# Match sequence of zero or more characters except a given character

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

This looks like it should be simple: I want to match an "i" followed by an "o" with an arbitrary (possibly zero-length) sequence of characters in between, unless that sequence also contains an "i". Without this constraint it's easy: `___~~"i"~~___~~"o"~~___`. This will match "histology", but it will also match "adventitious". I've tried using a conditional or a predicate test in the pattern but I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: If there is "i" between them, then this second "i" and "o" will match Your pattern. You have to tell more precisely what do You want. Only one "i" in a string or maybe You do not want to happen "i"~~___~~"i".

Comment: The pattern should be something like `___ ~~ "i" ~~ Longest[Except["i"] ...] ~~ "o" ~~ ___`, but this doesn't work. Someone may correct me, but this may not be expressible as a regular expression (which is a requirement for string patterns). I spent some time a while ago looking for a way to match all except a certain string using regular expressions, eventually finding that it isn't possible.

Comment: @OleksandrR. "*i" ~~ ___?(! MemberQ[Characters[#], "r"] &) ~~ "o*" may work sometimes. I could try to write more general pattern but there is no precise question here. By definition David's problem can not be solved in this form.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I think the documentation said `Longest` is the default strategy, so `Longest[Except["i"] ...]` will not override the `Longest` on the leading `___`, which will be matched first, so will *eat* any char including `"i"` until the last one before some "o".

Comment: Do you require something like `(StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "i" ~~ ___ ~~ "o" ~~ ___] && 
    StringFreeQ[#, ___ ~~ "i" ~~ ___ ~~ 
      "i" ~~ ___]) & /@ {"histology", "adventitious"}`.  Or maybe `Short[Pick[#, 
    StringFreeQ[#, ___ ~~ "i" ~~ ___ ~~ "i" ~~ ___] & /@ #] &@
  DictionaryLookup[___ ~~ "i" ~~ ___ ~~ "o" ~~ ___], 10]`

Comment: Are you looking to extract the text between "i" and "o", where there are no other "i"s present, or are looking to match an entire word? If the latter, should "adventitious" match, or not? Currently, it meets the conditions implied by your pattern.

Comment: @Silvia I thought it was `Longest` by default unless a `Longest` appears literally in the pattern, but I could be wrong. Anyway, I tried `Shortest` around the outer `RepeatedNull`s, but it made no difference--it still doesn't work. (Actually, that's the first thing I tried, but then I changed it to a single `Longest` as what I thought was a simplification before posting my comment above.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As commented by Kuba, I'm not sure what is exactly you want, but you might want to try this way:

```
StringMatchQ[#,
   Except["i"] ... ~~ "i" ~~ Except["i"] ... ~~ "o" ~~ ___
   ] & /@ {"histology", "adventitious"}
```

> {True, False}

Or the regular expression version:

```
StringMatchQ[#,
   RegularExpression["[^i]*i[^i]*o.*"]
   ] & /@ {"histology", "adventitious"}
```

> {True, False}

**Note:**

Despite `Longest` is the default strategy for `StringExpression`, it seems working differently on `List` and on `String`.

- On `List`:

  ```
  {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} /. {x__, Longest[y__], z__} :> {{x}, {y}, {z}}
  ```

  > ```
  > {{a}, {b, c, d, e, f}, {g}}
  > ```

  ```
  {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} /. {x__, y__, z__} :> {{x}, {y}, {z}}
  ```

  > ```
  > {{a}, {b}, {c, d, e, f, g}}
  > ```
- On `String`:

  ```
  StringCases["abcdefg",
   x : __ ~~ Longest[y : __] ~~ z : __ :> {x, y, z}
   ]
  ```

  > ```
  > {{"abcde", "f", "g"}}
  > ```

  ```
  StringCases["abcdefg",
   x : __ ~~ y : __ ~~ z : __ :> {x, y, z}
   ]
  ```

  > ```
  > {{"abcde", "f", "g"}}
  > ```

So you'll have to indicate explicitly that the leading part should not contain `"i"` (so `Except["i"] ...` instead of `___`) to enforce the middle part `"i" ~~ Except["i"] ... ~~ "o"` actually matching the *longest* pattern. I personally guess that is because string match is greedy and the leading part is matched before the middle part.

**Supplement:**

There is [a great free tool](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) for regex debugging, which can show the matching step by step. Also [a useful online tester](http://www.debuggex.com/). (I learnt them from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2348694/935879).)

Comment: It should be noted that `RegularExpression["[^i]*i[^i]*o.*"]` does match part of "adventitious" and using it with `StringCases` will return "tious". Of course, I interpret the OPs original pattern to match `"i[^i]*o"`.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes it is. I think it because `StringMatchQ` compares the whole string with the pattern, while `StringCases` will compare all sub-string. I interpret what OP wants based on the statement: *an "i" followed by an "o" with an arbitrary (possibly zero-length) sequence of characters in between, unless that sequence also contains an "i"*.

Comment: That's how I interpret it, too, but that allows for any character prior to the last (and matching) "i". What is needed is clarification by the OP if this is what he intends. +1, btw.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks. I think we'll have to wait and see what OP really wants.

Comment: Thanks, Silvia. The first one using `Except` with `RepeatedNull` is what I was looking for. `Except` takes a list so `Except[{"a","e","i","o","u"}]...` means anything but vowels, for example.

Comment: That's one way to do it, +1. Still, `StringMatchQ[{"histology", "adventitious", "pious", "bilious"}, a : Shortest[StartOfString ~~ ___ ~~ "i"] ~~  b : Longest[Except["i"] ...] ~~  c : Shortest["o" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfString] /; (Print[a, "/", b, "/", c]; True)]` prints "hi/stol/ogy", "adventiti//ous", "pi//ous", and "bili//ous". In other words, even being very specific about what parts are to be the longest and shortest, the result still isn't as expected. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks. I think it is because the `a~~b~~c` pattern divides a whole string, e.g. `"adventitious"`, into 3 parts, in which part `b` must NOT have `"i"`, so even part `a` is shortest, it has to extend to include all `"i"`s before the part `c`. Adding a `___` between `a` and `b` will solve the problem. In regex form, it's `"^(.*?i).*([^i]*)(o.*?)$"` instead of `"^(.*?i)([^i]*)(o.*?)$"`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. There is [a great free tool](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) for regex debugging, which can show the matching step by step. Also [a useful online tester](http://www.debuggex.com/). Learnt them from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2348694/935879).

Comment: @OleksandrR. A `StringExpression` version: `StringCases[{"histology","adventitious","pious","bilious"},a:Shortest[StartOfString~~___~~"i"]~~b:Shortest[___]~~c:Except["i"]...~~d:Shortest["o"~~___~~EndOfString]:>Sequence@@{a,b,c,d}]//Grid[#,Frame->All]&`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. You're welcome. :)

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for acceptance. Please see my **supplement** part, in case you might need them.

Comment: Thanks for that. The regex coach utility is going in my validation toolkit.